# I'm stuck with regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm stuck with regular expressions in Python...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

combi="ABBAEAADCA"
one_a = len(re.findall('[^A](A)[^A]', combi))
print("A:"+str(one_a))
```

I try to make this variable (one_a) contain the number of A's that appear alone (3) but it does not count those at the beginning and end of lines so....

```
one_a = len(re.findall('\A(A)[^A]', combi))
print("A ini:"+str(one_a))
one_a += len(re.findall('[^A](A)[^A]', combi))
print("A_cen:"+str(one_a))
one_a += len(re.findall('[^A](A)\Z', combi))
print("A_end:"+str(one_a))
```

but it didn't work either when in this particular case the value that should stay in the variable should be 3.
I would appreciate knowing what I am missing or what mistake I am making.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a negated character class `[^A]` matches a single character, and `\A` asserts the start of the string.

To get the A's that stand alone you can negative lookarounds asserting not A directly to the left and right:

```
(?<!A)A(?!A)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vyFMX4/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dW0yCG).

```
import re

combi="ABBAEAADCA"
one_a = len(re.findall('(?<!A)A(?!A)', combi))
print("A:"+str(one_a))
```

Output

```
A:3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine start-of-string (`^`) and end of string (`$`) with regular character classes through the or (`|`) operator.

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|[^A])A(?:$|[^A])', combi)
```

This gives you all substrings where `A` is either surrended by start of string and end of string, start of string and not-A, not-A or end of string or not-A and not-A.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|[^A])A(?:$|[^A])', combi)
['AB', 'BAE', 'CA']
```

Applying `len` to this list gives you the count of single A's.

Comment: Thank you so much...it's just what I needed.

Comment: Why does the last one not detect sometimes?

Comment: Do you have any examples of where it fails?

Comment: All are solved... TYVM